# How can I remove the glass domes from my light fixtures?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

This is embarrassing to ask, but I can't figure out how to change the light bulbs in my house.

The light fixtures are unusual and when I first bought my house I thought they were a selling point because they looked so lovely and unique. But now I can't figure out how to change the bulbs when they burn out.

I have tried rotating and pulling down on it, but the nuts prevent any movement. I have tried looking for secret latches, etc., but nothing has worked.

I've shown the fixtures to others and no one can quite figure it out. I have three that still work and two that have been burned out for over a year. Please help! And thank you.

[image: Light fixture]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Where are the "nuts"? Could you post a picture of them? Could you loosen them?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could stand on a chair and get a couple of pictures up near to ceiling showing the part of the light fixture between the top of the globe and the ceiling. A picture from two different sides would help greatly to get you an answer.

Comment: Have you tried rotating counter-clockwise?

Comment: You added more photos but none show us the interface between the globe/cover and the fixture ( right at the top near the ceiling. ) from what i can see there are no visible connectors but you mentioned nuts, nuts?

Comment: First picture looks like it has a space cut out that a finger could go into near the ceiling.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like fixtures I have had, which are held in place by three screws.  It's hard to be certain from the photo, but if it is like this, then you should loosen the screws by hand bit by bit until you are able to remove the globe.  That should expose the bulb and the socket it's screwed into.

If not, then please climb up higher to take a photograph that shows the part of the globe that comes closest to the ceiling.

Comment: Thank you! I added some more photos. Does this help? Thank you again for looking!

Comment: @SweetTea - The additional photos do not help. You need to get some close up pictures from two sides of the part of the light fixture between the top of the globe and the ceiling.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like its threaded on. Get some rubber coated gloves and a soft rubber mallet. Tap around the edges *lightly* and apply upward pressure, while turning at the same time. The rubber coating will give you more leverage across the dome face and the tapping vibrations will help break the dome free.

Comment: That's what I think too, screwed on. I would not resort to tapping the glass unless you try unscrewing it and it doesn't move. Rubber gloves is a great idea though.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to see but it must be threaded on. Imagine screwing the lid of a mason jar to the ceiling and screwing the jar in, now unscrew it. Just be careful as the glass is likely not as strong as a mason jar and is more susceptible to breaking.